# Add "Edit" button to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am familiar with this code: `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem`.

See this code:

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tblTasks: UITableView! // declaring this allows you to reload the tableView to update your items

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
```

I have the code that allows for the edit button to be present, yet no edit button is to be seen in my app nor the storyboard.

I am a Swift beginner, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stock "Edit" button is only available on `UITableViewController`. For other view controller types you'll have to create a button yourself.

Comment: since iOS 10.0+ you can use `self.editButtonItem` in any `UIViewController`   https://stackoverflow.com/a/64829238/1885345

Answer (score 2):

If you add it into `navigationItem` you should embed that view controller into `UINavigationController` to see that button.
You will not see that button in Storyboard because you set it in code. In Storyboard you setup only initial state of the controller.

How to setup editing mode in `UIViewController` subclass:

There is `editButtonItem` variable in `UIViewController`. If you add it on screen, `setEditing(_:,animated:)` will be triggered when user tap that button.
Also it will change button text between `Edit` and `Done` according to ViewController's `isEditing` state.
You can get current state from `self.isEditing`
Do not forget to call `super.setEditing(_:animated:)`, or it will not change state of the button and view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
   super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
   // custom code to handle edit mode
}
```

[editButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621471-editbuttonitem) (iOS 10.0+)
[isEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621498-isediting) (iOS 2.0+)
[setEditing(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621378-setediting) (iOS 2.0+)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own edit button, like:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("editTableView"))
```

**And then:**

```
func editTableView()
{
    if self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title == "Edit"
    {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = "Done"
        //edit your tableView Here!
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = "Edit"
        //when youre finishing editing
    }


}
```